# When are two measures equivalent?

Tags: measure-theory

Given to measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, with the relation $d\nu = f d \mu$, $f$ measurable and non-negative, then we know that $\nu << \mu$ (the Radon Nikodym theorem proves that the converse also holds).

Under what condition on $f$  is $\mu << \nu$, i.e. the two measures are equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent iff $f > 0$ $\mu$-a.e.

This is immediate from the standard fact that for $f \ge 0$ and any measurable set $A$, we have $\int_A f\,d\mu = 0$ if and only if $f = 0$ $\mu$-a.e. on $A$.